# How do I get the largest Percent Change with the Corresponding ticker using If statements (not max function)?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I need to add functionality to my script to return the stock with the "Greatest % increase", "Greatest % decrease", and "Greatest total volume".

**I was hoping my code would store the largest percent_change value every time g is greater than it, but the output just saves the very last ticker (on row 400) and 0.**

```
greatest_increase = -1
For e = 2 To 400

If Cells(e, 11).Value > Cells(e + 1, 11).Value Then
n = Cells(e, 9).Value
g = Cells(e, 11).Value

If g > greatest_increase Then
greatest_ticker = n
greatest_increase = g

Cells(2, 15).Value = greatest_increase
Cells(2, 16).Value = greatest_ticker

End If
End If
Next e

End Sub
```

Comment: remove the `If Cells(e, 11).Value > Cells(e + 1, 11).Value Then` block. And move the `Cells(2, 15).Value = greatest_increase : Cells(2, 16).Value = greatest_ticker` after the `Next e`

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```
    greatest_increase = -1
    For e = 2 To 400
        If Cells(e, 11).Value > greatest_increase Then
            greatest_ticker = Cells(e, 9).Value
            greatest_increase = Cells(e, 11).Value
        End If
    Next e
    Cells(2, 15).Value = greatest_increase
    Cells(2, 16).Value = greatest_ticker
```

---

Excel formula is also a good option.

| Cell | Formula |
| --- | --- |
| G2 | =XLOOKUP(H2,C:C,A:A) |
| G3 | =XLOOKUP(H3,C:C,A:A) |
| G4 | =XLOOKUP(H4,D:D,A:A) |
| H2 | =MAX(C:C) |
| H3 | =MIN(C:C) |
| H4 | =MAX(D:D) |

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WorksheetFunction.Max` (VBA version) to save yourself the time of looping through your rows:

```
' Get max value in column K (from row 2 up to row 400)
greatest_ticker = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Cells(2, "K"), Cells(400, "K")))
```